# How to submit an update after an app has been transferred

Tags: ios

I transferred an iOS app to a different account, but now I need to submit an update to that app.

I cannot figure out how to do this. If I use the team that now has the app I get an error stating that a diff team was used to sign the original. However, it will not work if I use the original account either since that account no longer has the app.

Comment: Have you modified the code signing to use the new team's credentials?

Comment: Yes, right now it is returning this error, however: `"ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle '  ' at bundle path 'Payload/.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate"`

Comment: Please post your signing configuration here (obfuscate private details if necessary).